# How can I make setuptools install a package from another source that's also available on pypi with the same version number?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils, easy-install

It's a similar question to [How can I make setuptools install a package that's not on PyPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472430/how-can-i-make-setuptools-install-a-package-thats-not-on-pypi) but not the same.

As I would like to use the forked version of some package, setuptools ignore the dependency link (as it has the same version number).

Is there a way to force using the link from the dependency_links? Or is the only way to change the version number in the forked repo?

```
requires = [
    ...
    'pyScss==1.1.3'
    ...

dependencies = [
    'https://github.com/nadavshatz/pyScss/zipball/master#egg=pyScss-1.1.3'
]
```

---

**Update**

Weird, apparently it works if this package is the only one in the required list, that is not installed yet. If there's another missing package it will download it from pypi.

Comment: @IlyaBaryshev, sorry but I only use the workaround I describe in the update. installing/updating all packages, then uninstall this specific one and then it's the only missing package - in this case it will take the link from the dependencies

Comment: I'm authoring a package, so it's not an option. I'm thinking about vendoring all dependencies inside my package, seem like an only option considering buggy setuptools behavior.

Comment: Might this be a solution to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17442663/368102?

Answer (score 10):

I believe you can just use `dependency_links` as described in that question:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name = 'mypkg',
    version = '0.0.1',
    description = 'Foo',
    author = 'bar',
    author_email = 'bar@example.com',
      install_requires = ['pyScss==1.1.3'],
      dependency_links = [
      'https://github.com/nadavshatz/pyScss/zipball/master#egg=pyScss-1.1.3'
      ]
    )
```

Tested using `python setup.py develop`

You probably want to rename the egg to emphasize it's a fork http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0386/

Outside of the setup.py you can enforce this locally using `requirements.txt` and `pip`. Whilst this won't make your package depend on the fork you can easily document it as the way to install.

```
$ cat requirements.txt
https://github.com/nadavshatz/pyScss/zipball/master#egg=pyScss-1.1.3
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: actually that's what i'm doing... in the `setup` call i pass `install_requires = requires` and `dependency_links = dependencies`. which is basically the same code as yours.

Answer (score 8):

I ended up doing something very similar to the answer in [stackoverflow.com/a/17442663/368102](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442663/368102).

I need a `requests-file` github package that name-conflicts with a different `requests-file` package in PyPi.  They both have a version 1.0, and the PyPi version has some higher versions.

The workaround in my `ias_tools/setup.py` looks like this:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        'requests-file<=99.99',
    ],
    dependency_links=[
        'https://github.com/jvantuyl/requests-file/archive/b0a7b34af6e287e07a96bc7e89bac3bc855323ae.zip#egg=requests-file-99.99'
    ]
)
```

In my case, I'm using `pip` so I also had to use `--process-dependency-links`:

```
% pip install --process-dependency-links ./ias_tools
You are using pip version 6.0.6, however version 6.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Processing ./ias_tools
  DEPRECATION: Dependency Links processing has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Collecting requests-file<=99.99 (from ias-tools==0.1)
  Downloading https://github.com/jvantuyl/requests-file/archive/b0a7b34af6e287e07a96bc7e89bac3bc855323ae.zip
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=1.1.0 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests-file<=99.99->ias-tools==0.1)
Installing collected packages: ias-tools, requests-file
  Running setup.py install for ias-tools
  Running setup.py install for requests-file
Successfully installed ias-tools-0.1 requests-file-1.0
```

I'm not too worried about the deprecation notice, as [a pull request was submitted to pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/1955) to deprecate the deprecation (after a [discussion about it](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/1955)).

Comment: My build command was `pip install --upgrade -e .`, and I also needed to add `--process-dependency-links`. Thanks for including that piece of info.