# Force setuptools to use dependency_links to install mysqlclient

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm using Windows, and I need to install the WHL file from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient).  Here's what I have in setup.py:

```
install_requires=['mysqlclient==1.3.7',
...
dependency_links=['https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/m/mysqlclient/mysqlclient-1.3.7-cp27-none-win32.whl#md5=e9e726fd6f1912af78e2bf6ab56c02f3',]
```

However, setuptools is downloading the tar.gz file instead and attempting to build, which won't work on my system.  I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442663/2233706) and changed my `install_requires` to use `mysqlclient<=1.3.7`, but I still get the same problem.  Here is the output:

```
Searching for mysqlclient<=1.3.7
Reading https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/P/Pillow/Pillow-2.7.0-cp27-none-win32.whl#md5=ebc4ef88a8dd39ed484206323a8d557a
Reading https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/m/mysqlclient/mysqlclient-1.3.7-cp27-none-win32.whl#md5=e9e726fd6f1912af78e2bf6ab56c02f3
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/mysqlclient/
Best match: mysqlclient 1.3.7
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/mysqlclient/mysqlclient-1.3.7.tar.gz#md5=2ec5a96cbd9fd6ef343fa9b581a67fc4
Processing mysqlclient-1.3.7.tar.gz
Running mysqlclient-1.3.7\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\uuu\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-wt7fkw\mysqlclient-1.3.7\egg-dist-tmp-ubrs4f
error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I don't have any issues with install Pillow using the link in the dependency_links.  Is there a way to force setup.py to use the dependency link?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up manually installing the package as a part of the post install:

```
from setuptools.command.install import install as _install
import pip

class install(_install):
  def run(self):
    _install.do_egg_install(self)

    # Even when dependeny link to mysqlclient is specified, setuptools still installs
    # from pypi, which does not work on Windows.  Therefore, manually install mysqlclient
    if os.name == 'nt':
      pip.main(['install', 'https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/m/mysqlclient/mysqlclient-1.3.7-cp27-none-win32.whl#md5=e9e726fd6f1912af78e2bf6ab56c02f3'])
    else:
      pip.main(['install', 'mysqlclient==1.3.7'])

setup(
      cmdclass={'install': install},
...
)
```

There are [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806485/execute-a-python-script-post-install-using-distutils-setuptools) that call `_install.run()`, but that didn't work for me.  I had to use `do_egg_install()`.