# Including direct dependency download links in setup.py

Tags: python, egg, sourceforge, setup.py

Can one specify direct download links for Python egg dependencies?

I have Skype4Py as a dependency and easy_install seems to fail to download the file correctly from sourceforge.net (sourceforge.net issue). The resulting tar file is scrambled. https://github.com/stigkj/Skype4Py/issues/3

To work around this issue I'd like to specify a direct download link for Skype4Py archive to avoid the issues with sourceforge.net.

Comment: Adding dependency_links in the setup might help here. See this stackoverflow question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472430/how-can-i-make-setuptools-install-a-package-thats-not-on-pypi

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I highly recommend using pip [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3220404/95735) of easy_install as it's simply better in [nearly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13233935/95735) every aspect.

You can't specify direct download link directly in `setup.py` but that's a good thing. Decision where to look for a dependency should be made at installation time. Pip has a few [`options`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#alternate-package-repositories) allowing to configure where to look for packages; `--index-url`, `--extra-index-url` and `--find-links`. However in your situation I think the simplest solution would be to install the dependency that fails to install from its *default* location using some alternate location first and then install the package that uses it like so:

`pip install alternate_location_of_dependency`
`pip install some_package_having_above_depedency`

Taking [`human_curl`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/human_curl/) package, which depends on pycurl2 package, as an example that might be:

`pip install https://github.com/pycurl2/pycurl2.github.com/archive/master.zip`
`pip install human_curl`

Comment: Ok, the answer is that you *cannot* specify locations in setup.py?