# Problems with installing package from dependency_links

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Here is my setup.py:

```py
    setup(
        ...
        install_requires=['GEDThriftStubs'],
        dependency_links=['git+ssh://user@git.server.com/ged-thrift-stubs.git#egg=GEDThriftStubs'],
...)
```

Then I create package:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

Then I try to install it:

> pip install  file://path/package-0.0.1.tar.gz

And get this in terminal:

```
Downloading/unpacking GEDThriftStubs (from package==0.0.1)
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement GEDThriftStubs (from package==0.0.1)
No distributions at all found for GEDThriftStubs (from package==0.0.1)
```

And in pip.log messages like this:

```
Skipping link git+ssh://user@git.server.com/ged-thrift-stubs.git#egg=GEDThriftStubs; wrong project name (not gedthriftstubs)
```

And I don't have anywhere in my project that exact name "gedthriftstubs", if it matters.

But this works fine:

```
pip install git+ssh://user@git.server.com/ged-thrift-stubs.git#egg=GEDThriftStubs
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Are you trying `sudo python setup.py sdist` or just `python setup.py sdist`?

Comment: I run both commands without sudo under one user and inside one virtualenv.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pip ignores dependency\_links in setup.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518499/pip-ignores-dependency-links-in-setup-py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```bash
$ pip install --process-dependency-links file://path/package-0.0.1.tar.gz
```

Note that this tag is removed from `pip` in pip 1.6. [See this article on pip.pypa.io](https://pip.pypa.io/en/develop/dependency_links.html) for more information.

> In pip 1.5 processing dependency links was deprecated and it was removed completely in pip 1.6.

There's also a [lengthy discussion ( issue #1519 )](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/1519) regarding pip & dependency links

If that doesn't work, you may also need to add a version suffix on your link, like this:

```
git+ssh://user@git.server.com/ged-thrift-stubs.git#egg=GEDThriftStubs-0.0.1
```

where `0.0.1` is the `version` specified in the setup.py of `ged-thrift-stubs`