# Install python package from svn using dependency_links in setup.py

Tags: python, svn, tortoisesvn, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to install hw3 package which has a dependency package hw2. My setup.py looks as follows -

```
setup(
    name='hw3',
    version='0.1',
    packages = find_packages(),
    install_requires = 'hw2',
    dependency_links = [
        r'svn+https://server.local/svn/Libraries/testPkg2/trunk#egg=hw2'
    ]
)
```

I get the following error when I run python setup.py install in windows cmd

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+https://server.local/svn/Libraries/testPkg2/trunk'
svn: E125002: Undefined tunnel scheme 'https'
```

Alternatively, I have requirements.txt which is as follows

```
svn+https://server.local/svn/Libraries/testPkg2/trunk#egg=hw2
```

If I run pip install -r requirements.txt, it installs hw2 package successfully.

My svn version is

> svn, version 1.9.7 (r1800392)    compiled Aug  8 2017, 22:14:48 on
>   x86-microsoft-windows

how to resolve this error? Thanks

I am getting the same error for 'http' and 'svn'.

For 'ssh' it is

```
svn: E170012: Can't create tunnel
svn: E720002: Can't create tunnel: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: have you tried changing it to `http` that could be the problem, also not sure about authentication but perhaps you need to `ssh`

Comment: @aws_apprentice i tried ssh and http as well and got similar error

Comment: @gdRow Did you ever find a solution? Having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it directly with the `install_requires` option (requires pip>=18.1):

```
setup(
    name='hw3',
    version='0.1',
    packages = find_packages(),
    install_requires = ['hw2@svn+https://server.local/svn/Libraries/testPkg2/trunk#egg=hw2'],
)
```

See also this answer to a related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/54216163/13835019.