# Add a custom wheel file as a dependency in setup.py?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm working on a project where one of the dependencies is actually a `.whl` that isn't on pypi (i.e. I had to download the wheel direct from the author and `pip` install it directly). In my `setup.py` file, is there a way to do something like:

```
install_requires=[
    'library.whl',
    'matplotlib==2.2.2',
    'numpy==1.14.2',
    'opencv-python==3.4.0.12',
    'Pillow==5.1.0',
    'PyYAML==3.12',
],
```

Or something along these lines since its not on pypi (and I would just add the `library.whl` in the `MANIFEST.in` file or something)? If not, is there a recommended way to do this for this type of situation? I'd ideally like to solve this in the `setup.py` file so I can install my library easily with a single `pip install`

Answer (score 3):

As provided in the comment use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518499/pip-ignores-dependency-links-in-setup-py/54216163#54216163) for more information.

#### TL;DR:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
         'repo @ https://github.com/user/archive/master.zip#egg=repo-1.0.0'],
    ...
)
```

#### DEPRECATED:

According to the [docs](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html#packages-not-on-pypi), you need to specify `dependency_links` in your setup arguments:

```
DEPRECATED
```

Comment: Deprecated. See more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518499/pip-ignores-dependency-links-in-setup-py#comment94736800_13587734

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to use a [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-from-wheels) requirement files to install your dependencies. A [requirement file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format) specify each library and required version. You can use a URL to point to your wheel.

Example:

```
http://host/path/to/library.whl
matplotlib==2.2.2
numpy==1.14.2
opencv-python==3.4.0.12
Pillow==5.1.0
PyYAML==3.12
```

And simply specify ‘library’ to your `setup.py` file.

**Edit**

The best practice is to have an additional PyPi server like [DevPi](https://devpi.net/docs/devpi/devpi/stable/%2Bd/index.html). And change your pip [configuration file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file) to add this repository. Of course your `library.whl` must be pushed in this private server.

Example of `pip.conf`:

```
[global]
index-url = http://yourserver/group/user/

[install]
trusted-host = yourserver

[download]
trusted-host = yourserver

[list]
format = columns
```

You may also need to configure your `.pypirc` file:

```
[distutils]
index-servers = pypi
                private

[pypi]
repository: http://pypi.python.org/pypi
username:your-username
password:your-password

[private]
repository: http://yourserver
username:your-login
password:your-password
```

That way you could push your releases on your private server:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel upload -r private register -r private
```

Comment: What do you mean by "And simply specify ‘library’ to your setup.py file." ? If I provide a `requirements.txt` file does that mean people have to download it and then do `pip install -r requirements.txt`? Or can I supply a `requirements.txt` to my `setup.py` file somehow?

Comment: In your `setup.py` you need to specify the minimum requirements for the application to work, so "library" is required. The `requirements.txt` usually specify the exact requirements with fixed versions. Note: the 2nd solution is better (the one with a private repository).

Comment: We sometimes speak about "abstract" (in `setup.py`) and "concrete" (in `requirements.txt`) requirements. See: https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/