# pyaudio cannot be installed from PyPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pyaudio

I try to install `pyaudio` with `pip` in Python 3.8 and the following error raises. In a Conda environment, it can be installed with `conda` correctly.

> ```
> C:\Users\csevast>\dev\Python38\python -m pip install pyaudio
> Collecting pyaudio
>   Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
> Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
>   Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
>   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>    command: 'C:\dev\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\csevast\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9eju90dy\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\csevast\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9eju90dy\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\csevast\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-9onoc0i8'
>        cwd: C:\Users\csevast\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9eju90dy\pyaudio\
>   Complete output (17 lines):
>   running bdist_wheel
>   running build
>   running build_py
>   creating build
>   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
>   copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
>   running build_ext
>   building '_portaudio' extension
>   creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
>   creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
>   creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\dev\Python38\include -IC:\dev\Python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
>   _portaudiomodule.c
>   C:\dev\Python38\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
>   src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
>   src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
>   error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
>  ----------------------------------------
>   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
>   Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
> Failed to build pyaudio
> Installing collected packages: pyaudio
>     Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
>     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>      command: 'C:\dev\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\csevast\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9eju90dy\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\csevast\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9eju90dy\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\csevast\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dyojsv6s\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\dev\Python38\Include\pyaudio'
>          cwd: C:\Users\csevast\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9eju90dy\pyaudio\
>     Complete output (17 lines):
>     running install
>     running build
>     running build_py
>     creating build
>     creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
>     copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
>     running build_ext
>     building '_portaudio' extension
>     creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
>     creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
>     creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
>     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\dev\Python38\include -IC:\dev\Python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
>     _portaudiomodule.c
>     C:\dev\Python38\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
>     src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
>     src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
>     error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
>     ----------------------------------------
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\dev\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\csevast\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9eju90dy\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\csevast\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9eju90dy\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\csevast\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dyojsv6s\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\dev\Python38\Include\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.
> ```

Comment: Have a look at the solutions from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. As I see `pyaudio` has to be recompiled.

Comment: There are prebuilt binary versions (e.g. https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio).

Comment: Actually, my problem is that I cannot set PyAudio as a perquisite in the `setup.py` file to create a distribution package e.g. in PyPI. Is there any solution to include the PyAudio package in the wheel file of another package?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521033/add-a-custom-wheel-file-as-a-dependency-in-setup-py
I have not checked this myself though.