# Installing private repos with pipenv and setup.py fails

Tags: python, pipenv

I have a private library (say mypack) that I'm using at work which depends on another private library (say otherpack). I've mentioned the dependency in the `setup.py` of mypack.

```
setup(name='mypack', version='0.1',
      install_requires=['otherpack==0.1'],
      dependency_links=['git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/theSage21/otherpack#egg=otherpack-0.1'])
```

This works if you do `python setup.py install`.

I'm trying to use `pipenv` to lock the dependencies (there are others besides otherpack) via `pipenv install -e . --verbose`.

It appears that pipenv only searches PyPi for the otherpack and does not use dependency_links. Am I doing something wrong? Example code at https://gitlab.com/theSage21/mypack

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that this arises in `pip` and has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518499/pip-ignores-dependency-links-in-setup-py). Since `--process-dependency-links` no longer seems to be set for deprecation the above issues was solved with:

```
$ PIP_PROCESS_DEPENDENCY_LINKS=1 pipenv install -e . --python 3
```