# Install a library from a private PyPi within setuptools' extras_require

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, extra

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to install a library from a private PyPi within the **extras_require** of **setuptools.setup**.

Let's say I have the following **extras**:

```
setup(
    ...

    "extras_require": {
        "foo": ["lib1==1.0.0", "lib2==1.0.0", "lib3==1.0.0"]
    },
    ...
)
```

Now, I'd like to add another dependency (**lib4==1.0.0**) that I have in my private PyPi, something like this (it's just a POC):

```
setup(
    ...

    "extras_require": {
        "foo": ["lib1==1.0.0", "lib2==1.0.0", "lib3==1.0.0",
                "lib4==1.0.0 --extra-index-url http://localhost/libraries/"]
    },
    ...
)
```

Is that possible? If not, can you please tell me how I can address this problem?

Comment: Would that help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57704447/11138259

Comment: It works! Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent for \`--find-links\` in \`setup.py\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689387/equivalent-for-find-links-in-setup-py)

Comment: Yes, it does. It works as expected.