# How to require packages from multiple indexes in setup.py?

Tags: pip, setuptools, python-packaging

I am developing a python library which depends on package `A` from PyPI and `B` from another index. How do I specify the dependencies, given `B` is already listed in PyPI?

Comment: The meta info in a python package regarding dependencies does not include info on how to get it, that'ss part of the deployment process. Can you pre-install `B` with `--index-url` pointing to the alternative index before installing your library?

Comment: @Arne my library is supposed to be a dependency itself, so it should be installed automatically.

Comment: Then maybe this answer can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/13587734/962190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `setuptools` you can specify `dependency_links` as an argument to the call to `setuptools.setup` in your `setup.py` script. See the [setuptools documentation on "Dependencies that aren’t in PyPI"](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi).

This won't work well when installing with `pip` though. There's currently no good way to enforce this on the users of your package and for good reason. Instead you will have to document your package well enough in order to instruct the users of your package to install it with the correct `pip` options: [`--index-url`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-index-url), [`--extra-index-url`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-extra-index-url), or [`--find-links`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-f).

*Untested:* For the comfort of the users of your package you could provide a [`constraints.txt` file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#constraints-files) summing up the previously mentioned `pip` options.