# Extra Python package index url with setuptools now that dependency_links is deprecated?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools

Formerly with setuptools, a Python dependency that needed to be installed from an extra index URL could just be added to `dependency_links`. Example from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30064248/7039201):

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='somepackage',
    install_requires=[
        'somedep'
    ],
    dependency_links=[
        'https://pypi.example.org/pypi/somedep/'
    ]
    # ...
)
```

But now that `dependency_links` is ignored, how do I install a package from a different index url with setuptools? The [docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi) basically say to use VCS or `dependency_links`, but I'm unable to use the former and the latter doesn't work anymore.

Comment: This question has been asked many times already. Please search. -- Short answer you can't. You have to deal with this differently.

Comment: I don't think this specific question has been asked in the past 3 years since dependency_links has been deprecated. For example, the linked question I posted has people following up asking how to do it now. Any advice on how to deal with this differently?

Comment: @TrentMcCormick You can list extra URLs in the [`pip` command line](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#install-extra-index-url), environment variables or [configuration files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/). You cannot list them in `setup.py`.

Comment: Some pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57704447 (read the comments as well) -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58708235 -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57978269 -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/66909248 -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67344547 -- Sorry, I don't seem to find a good comprehensive canonical answer. -- Basically you should assume that `dependency_links` does not exist, it is now considered as somewhat of a "misfeature", and nowadays the user doing the install should be in charge of choosing the indexes, and not the creator of the package.