# How can I install a private module with public dependencies in pip?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I've found a few answers that relate to [dependency_links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472430/how-can-i-make-setuptools-install-a-package-thats-not-on-pypi) but they unfortunately have yet to work for me. I'm writing a python module. It's stored in a private pypi repo, and relies on a few dependencies stored both in the same private repo and the [public pypi repository](http://pypi.python.org/pypi):

```
setup(
# some other setup
name = 'mymodule',
install_requires = [
    'kazoo',
    'privateDependencyA',
    'privateDependencyB'
],
dependency_links = [
    "http://my.private.repo/eggs/#privateDependencyA",
    "http://my.private.repo/eggs/#privateDependencyB"
])
```

I store `mymodule` in my private repository, thus I try to install it:

```
pip install -i http://my.private.repo/eggs/ mymodule
```

That works just fine, but fails to find `kazoo`, which is  a public library. Thus I try the `-f` flag:

```
$ pip install -i http://my.private.repo/eggs/ -f http://pypi.python.org/ mymodule                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Downloading/unpacking mymodule
  Downloading mymoudle-<version>.tar.gz (unknown size): 3.1kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package mymodule

Downloading/unpacking kazoo (from mymodule)
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement kazoo (from mymodule)

Downloading/unpacking kazoo (from mymodule)
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement kazoo (from mymodule)
```

How can I download dependencies from the public pypi repository while simultaneously installing my module from my private one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `--extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple` to your command. It will first look at http://my.private.repo/eggs/ and then at https://pypi.python.org/simple.

Check out more information at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_wheel/#cmdoption-extra-index-url

Comment: This introduces a security vulnerability https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66242072/avoiding-dependency-confusion-in-python (!!!)
Always specify explicit versions of internal and external packages in requirements.txt.

Also could you confirm your source for this?

`It will first look at http://my.private.repo/eggs/ and then at https://pypi.python.org/simple.`

Seems like that's not always the case.