# How can I make setup tools install a github forked PyPI package?

Tags: python, github, fork, setuptools, pypi

Here is the example scenario.

There is a python package `not-mine` and I have just found a small bug in it. I find the source code on github and fork the repository. I make the necessary changes and submit a pull request. Unfortunately the package author is on vacation and I have a deadline.

I need a way to install my forked repository rather than the authors version living on PyPI. I have tried the following with no success:

```
install_requires = [
    'not-mine==1.0.0'
],
dependency_links = [
    'http://github.com/my-username/not-mine/tarball/master#egg=not-mine-1.0.0'
]
```

What am I missing?

Resources I have stumbled on while investigating the issue:
[How can I make setuptools install a package that's not on PyPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472430/how-can-i-make-setuptools-install-a-package-thats-not-on-pypi)

Comment: I have this same problem for a package I'm writing.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to point `pip` at the URL of your forked repo with your bugfix because `pip` [can install directly from git repos](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#vcs-support).

```
$ pip install git+git://github.com/my-username/not-mine#egg=not-mine
```

You can modify the `pip install` command to specify a particular commit, branch, tag, etc. with the "@" symbol before the "#".

```
$ pip install git+git://github.com/my-username/not-mine@bugfix_branch#egg=not-mine
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to install your forked forked package on your system you can simply clone the package to your system and use `python setup.py install` command to install that package locally on your system.

If you need to deploy application with your own modified package then, i recommend you to use the [python virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the project and locally clone it to your system.  Then refer to this local fork via following:

```
pip install -e ~/Repositories/some_local_fork_repo_path/
```

Where "~/Repositories/some_local_fork_repo_path/" is path to your local cloned forked project.  Then you can control what branch, etc. details on the other local cloned forked project independently of this project by simply working on that local project vs. this local project.