# setup.py not honoring PIP_INDEX_URL

Tags: python, pypi

I am running a local [pypi server](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver).  I can install packages from this server by either specifying it with the `-i` option of the `pip` command or by setting the `PIP_INDEX_URL` environment variable. When I install a package that has prerequisites, `setup.py` has historically honored the `PIP_INDEX_URL` environment variable, pulling the additional packages from my local server.

However, on a couple of systems that have been recently installed, it is behaving differently. Running, for instance, `python setup.py develop` fails because it tries to install prerequisites packages from *pypi.python.org*.

I have updated all of the related python packages (`python`, `distribute`, `virtualenv`, `pip`, etc...) on all the systems I'm testing on and continue to see this discrepancy. On my "original" system, `setup.py` downloads prerequisites from the pypi server specified in my `PIP_INDEX_URL` environment variable. On the newer systems, I can't seem to make it honor this variable.

What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like this was partially answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472430/how-can-i-make-setuptools-install-a-package-thats-not-on-pypi.  It doesn't explain why the environment variable is being inconsistently honored, but it does tell me how to solve my problem by specifying dependency_links.

Comment: And I finally found the culprit.  On the old server, I had a `~/.pydistutils` file which directed easy_install to use my pypi server.  Once I created this file on the new servers, my deployments worked again.  It still doesn't use the PIP_INDEX_URL variable, but this gives me a way around it.

Answer (score 3):

Create `setup.cfg` in the same folder as your `setup.py` with following content:

```
[easy_install]
allow_hosts = *.myintranet.example.com
```

---

From: http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#restricting-downloads-with-allow-hosts

> You can use the `--allow-hosts (-H)` option to restrict what domains EasyInstall will look for links and downloads on.
>
> `--allow-hosts=None` prevents downloading altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'll give that a try.  I'm still baffled as to why I see different behavior between systems running the same software, though.

Comment: @zenzic if you use `python setup.py develop`, then [`distutils`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/distutils.html) takes care of installation. 

For backgroud information there's an article that summarizes the (sorry) state of python packaging: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2012/6/22/hate-hate-hate-everywhere/

Comment: that is what I expected but not seeing.  I am still beating my head against this problem and not finding an acceptable solution.  What it comes down to is that `python setup.py develop` uses easy_install to install dependencies specified in setup.py (`install_requires`).  easy_install ignores the PIP_INDEX_URL environment variable.  I don't want to hardcode an index server in setup.py or setup.cfg, I want it to use the one specified in the environment.  Is there some better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue.  Fundamentally, `setup.py` is using `setuptools` which leverages `easy_install`, not `pip`.  Thus, it ignores any `pip-related` environment variables you set.

Rather than use `python setup.py develop` you can run pip (from the top of the package) `pip install -e .`   to produce the same effect.