# pip install python app from github, with non pypi dependecy

Tags: python, github, pip, setup.py

We wrote an application for ourselves which calls us on the phone, if our telescope has a problem. One can install this application (without prior cloning) like this:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/fact-project/shifthelper
```

and we like that our non-developer friends can install the app without prior cloning it. So far so good.

---

Now we pulled out part of the app into a little library, which one can install like this:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/fact-project/smart_fact_crawler
```

but we seem to be unable to tell `pip` in the setup.py how to install the required library before installing the app.

We tried using this:

```
#setup.py
....
dependency_links=[
    "git+http://github.com/fact-project/smart_fact_crawler.git#egg=smart_fact_crawler",
],
....
```

---

So how does one specify non pypi dependencies in the `setup.py`?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472430/how-can-i-make-setuptools-install-a-package-thats-not-on-pypi

Comment: Have you tried using option I suggested in my answer?

Comment: Have you tried using option I suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

From [Release Notes](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/) for pip 1.5 (2014-01-01)

> BACKWARD INCOMPATIBLE pip no longer respects dependency links by
>   default. Users may opt into respecting them again using
>   `--process-dependency-links`.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is all good and the deprecation of --process-dependency-link has since been (luckily) reverted.

The missing piece here is that pip requires an additional flag to actually use the listed links:

```
pip install ... --process-dependency-links ...
```

The Pull Request that was reverted - https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/1519