# Run a tensorflow code in distributed mode on google cloud ML

Tags: distributed-computing, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

Does anybody know what changes need to be made to trainer in order to run a job on distributed platform on google cloud ML ?

It will of great help if somebody can share few articles or docs about the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By and large, your distributed TensorFlow program will be exactly that -- distributed TensorFlow, with minimal -- or even no -- cloud-specific changes. The best resource for distributed TensorFlow is [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) on tensorflow.org. The tutorial walks you through the low-level way of doing things.

There is also a higher-level API, currently in contrib (so API may change and will move out of contrib in a future version), that simplifies the amount of boilerplate code you have to write for distributed training. The official tutorial is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn).

Once you've understood the general TensorFlow bits (whether high-level or low-level APIs), there are some specific elements that must be present in your code to get it to run on CloudML Engine. In the case of the low-level TensorFlow APIs, you'll need to parse the TF_CONFIG environment variable to setup your ClusterSpec. This is exemplified in [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census/tensorflowcore) (see specifically [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/01ed847eea06300d278ffcf1214021b487d3d463/census/tensorflowcore/trainer/task.py#L383) block of code).

One advantage of the higher-level APIs, is that all of that parsing is already taken care of for you. Your code should just generally work. See [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census/estimator). The important piece is that you will need to use [learn_runner.run()](https://github.com/agrawalnishant/tensorflow-1/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_runner.py) (see [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/b78bfc5e81dd33c4c95cd9f768ee10960f666764/census/estimator/trainer/task.py#L191) line), which will work locally and in the cloud to train your model.

Of course, there are other frameworks as well, e.g., [TensorFX](https://github.com/TensorLab/tensorfx/blob/master/README.md).

After you've structured your code appropriately, then you simply select an appropriate [scale tier](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#scaletier) that has multiple machines when launching your training job. (See [Chuck Finley's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43209918/1399222) answer for an example)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It gives me a starting point as i was confused about how to modify my code.

Comment: I have been able to run code in distributed environment but as of now every machine in the cloud is receiving the full data and generating output after averaging. 
I want to know how I can give distributed data to each machine in the cloud .

Comment: While submittng a job on gogle cloud ML, I am getting an error where main training python file i.e. task.py is not able to import a function from a python script in util folder.

Generally, we write : from util.xyz import abc

this is not getting called in the main task.py

Comment: I have been able to run this using gcloud local training but this problem occurs when i try to use gcloud job submit .

Comment: how to install a python package from github using setup.py ? I am trying to install kenlm module from github passing it in setup.py.... Please help ..need  answer urgently...

Comment: Local training works because it uses your system's setup. On the cloud you'll need to force certain libraries to be installe. RE: github, see
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3481388/1399222. dependency_links should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your model constructed with Tensorflow Estimators, the changes you need to do are very minimal. You can basically plug your code into e.g. [this boilerplate code](https://github.com/Fematich/mlengine-boilerplate).

Answer (score 0):

Is your question answered by the argument "scale-tier" in [Run Distributed Training in the Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/getting-started-training-prediction)?

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
   --job-dir $OUTPUT_PATH \
   --runtime-version 1.0 \
   --module-name trainer.task \
   --package-path trainer/ \
   --region $REGION \
   --scale-tier STANDARD_1 \
   -- \
   --train-files $TRAIN_DATA \
   --eval-files $EVAL_DATA \
   --train-steps 1000 \
   --verbose-logging true
```

Comment: Here's a direct link to the info about distributed training: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/getting-started-training-prediction#cloud-train-dist

Comment: i think this job submission will come at a later stage once i have modified my code as per distributed tensorflow.

Comment: I have been able to run code in distributed environment but as of now every machine in the cloud is receiving the full data and generating output after averaging. I want to know how I can give distributed data to each machine in the cloud

Comment: While submittng a job on gogle cloud ML, I am getting an error where main training python file i.e. task.py is not able to import a function from a python script in util folder.

Generally, we write : from util.xyz import abc

this is not getting called in the main task.py

Comment: @Appu did you get it to work? sounds like worth it's own question, but it's going to boil down to your setup.py. See  stackoverflow.com/a/40287409/1399222