# how to add a tar.gz githubfile to setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

From my `setup.py`:

```
requirements = [
    ...,
    'git+https://github.com/SergeySatskiy/cdm-pythonparser/archive/v2.0.1.tar.gz'
]

setup(
    install_requires=requirements,
    ...,
)
```

This does not work.
However, I know I can install the tar.gz by using plain

```
pip install git+https://github.com/SergeySatskiy/cdm-pythonparser/archive/v2.0.1.tar.gz
```

**Is there a way to set this up within my `setup.py` file?**

I have tried pulling it local but that did not work as well.
Also tried to do it without the `git+`, did not work either.

### Update

What I saw was that I can add the dependency to a kwarg called `dependency_links` like this:

```
setup(
   ...
   install_requires=requirements,
   dependency_links = ['http://github.com/SergeySatskiy/cdm-pythonparser/archive/v2.0.1.tar.gz']
)
```

But then it gets included always.
What I am trying to accomplish is that it gets included in the test environment. So I added it to the `tests_require`, but of course this works just like `install_requires` so that didn't help.

**Is there a way to only get this in my test environment?**

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: see https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi

Comment: Do you have any special constraints so you cannot upload it to PyPI as sdist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make setuptools install a package that's not on PyPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472430/how-can-i-make-setuptools-install-a-package-thats-not-on-pypi)

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
install_requires=['cdm-pythonparser @ http://github.com/SergeySatskiy/cdm-pythonparser/archive/v2.0.1.tar.gz']
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references), such direct references require a `file://` or other prefix prefix like `http://`

the way to specify it in `install_requires` is

```
install_requires = ["<package_name> @ http://<url_to_tar.gz>",]
```