# Python `setup.py` include non-python code from github release

Tags: python, github, pypi, setup.py

I want to tell `setup.py` to download release version of other repo that is not python. My target repo has release that can be downloaded using `https://github.com/USER/PACKAGE/archive/refs/tags/v1.0.0.zip`. This release is **not Python code**. How can I make `setup.py` to *install* that file (just place it, also unzip if zipped, so that my python code can access it)? Note that my python code itself should be able to be published on `pypi` and installed using `pip install mycode`

Background:

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472430/how-can-i-make-setuptools-install-a-package-thats-not-on-pypi), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612733/including-non-python-files-with-setup-py), and many others question, but can't find the exact solution for my use case.

I need this because some people make `python` bridge that make it possible to call non python code from python, for example [pybind](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) and [oct2py](https://github.com/blink1073/oct2py)